# How take name and id from a select

Tags: material-ui, react-hooks

I use react hooks to make a select. So far I can only take the id, but I can't take the name.

The select code:

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
  CountryGet().then(result => { setCountries(result); });
  }, []);

const onChangeCountry = e => {
    setSelectedCountry(e.target.value);   
  }

<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                  <InputLabel id="country_label">Country</InputLabel>
                  <Select id="country" value={selectedCountry} onChange={onChangeCountry}>
                    {countries.map((country) => (
                      <MenuItem  key={country.id} value={country.id}>
                        {country.countryName}
                      </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                  </Select>
                </FormControl>
```

I want in the selectCountry to have the Id and the name but so far I only get the id. How can get the name from the select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the default value in the useState is wrong. You need to provide the shape of your country object. I assume your country object looks something like

```
{
id:anumber,
countryName:"astring",
}
```

if this is the case, then you shoud do something like this

```
const [countries, setCountries] = useState([{id:0, countryName:""}]);
const [selectedCountry, setSelectedCountry] = useState({id:0, countryName:""});
```

Comment: It could be a method, but for this I must bind the country object to the value:<MenuItem  key={country.id} value={country}>
                        {country.country}
                      </MenuItem> It is another method because to the value I just want only to bind the id, not the object?

Comment: you can set the setCountry by filtering your array of countries using array.filter or array.find and get only the country that matches the selected id. But again, the easiest solution and most efficient would be set the county as the value, since this is what you are expecting to get at the end.